# Customize Notepad++ XML Tools plugin shortcuts

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I use the XML Tools Notepad++ plugin and its command "Pretty print", however I'd like to change it's shortcut. I was not able to find the command in the "Settings > Shortcut Mapper...", is there a way to do it?

Comment: morbac@gmail.com is the author, maybe if you tip him on Paypal he can help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you could not find it.
Go to Setting -> Shortcut Mapper, then click on "Plugin commands". All shortcuts used by plugins will be listed. You can filter them by typing: "pretty" on the filter box. You can then double-click or right then modify to modify the shortcut command.

[image]

Comment: Huh, turns out I am blind and didn't see that there are tabs, at all, in the manager. Also searching by "Pretty" in the default tab yielded no results, which is why I was discouraged.